# How to show an array of images in react native?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

how to show an array of images in react native ?, the images use URLs and are stored in firestore database this is the exact structure it is store as on the database lodash is being used to change the object of user to an array
[![the database structure][1]][1]

```
Object {
"book": "Robin hood", 
"photos": Array [ "https://picsum.photos/id/1001/5616/3744", "https://picsum.photos/id/1002/4312/2868", "https://picsum.photos/id/1003/1181/1772", ],
 }
```

i tried this but gotten and error saying ''Error while updating property 'src' of a view manged by: RCTImageView 
null 
Value for uri cannot be cast from ReadableVativeArray to String''

```
return this.props.user.map((details) => {
      return (

        <View >

        <Text>{details.book}</Text>

          <Image style={{ width: 350, height: 300 }} source={{ uri: details.photos }} />

        </View>

        );

    });
```

I also tried this,the console log is showing the images URLs and other data that was fetch, and the book details are showing but for some reason the images aren't showing on the screen

```
 return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>

        {this.props.user.map(details => {
          details.photos.map((image) => {
            console.log(image)
            return (
              <View>
                <Image style={{ width: 350, height: 300 }} source={{ uri: image }} />
              </View>
            );
          })
          return (
            <View>
                  <Text style={styles.b}>{details.book}</Text>
            </View>
          )
        })}
      </View>
    )


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLvci.png
```

Comment: You're mapping over the images, but not doing anything with them. They are disappearing into JS-land.

Comment: User is an object but you're iterating over it with a map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `details.photos.map` in your second example is not being included in the return value. Instead you want something like:

```
 return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>

        {this.props.user.map(details => {
          // save the result of the map call to a variable
          const photos = details.photos.map((image) => {
            console.log(image)
            return (
              <View key={image}>
                <Image style={{ width: 350, height: 300 }} source={{ uri: image }} />
              </View>
            );
          })
          return (
            <View>
                  // note the addition of the photos here
                  {photos}
                  <Text style={styles.b}>{details.book}</Text>
            </View>
          )
        })}
      </View>
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the "Object" refers to "this.props.user"
so, you try to iterate on an object and you can't, you can only iterate on an array, like the photos array.

try this:

```
return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>

    <Text>{this.props.user.book}</Text>

    {this.props.user.photos.map((photo) => {
      return (
        <Image style={{ width: 350, height: 300 }} source={{ uri: photo }} />
      );
    })}

  </View>
);
```

Comment: hi @RoiDayan i tried that and it throws this error '' Type Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.user.photos.map')''

Comment: i assumed that "this.props.user" returns the Object above.
which variable holds the Object?

Comment: hi @RoiDayan the object is being convert to an array with lodash that how the book name is showing but not the photos, user is the variable 'this.props.user.'